# How to add a PHP to my html table?

Tags: php, html, filesystems

I need to implement this PHP in my html file, this goes to a directory checks the files in there and creates a combobox with those options... now how can I can call this in a specific place in my html code.

```
<?php
$dir = 'xml/';

$exclude = array('somefile.php', 'somedir');

// Check to see if $dir is a valid directory
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  $contents = scandir($dir);

  echo '<select class="dropdown-toggle" id="combo">';

  foreach($contents as $file) {
  // This will exclude all filenames contained within the $exclude array
  // as well as hidden files that begin with '.'
  if (!in_array($file, $exclude) && substr($file, 0, 1) != '.') {
  echo '<option>'. $file .'</option>';
  }
  }

  echo '</select>';
  }
  else {
  echo "The directory <strong>". $dir ."</strong> doesn't exist.";
  }
?>
```

Comment: The question *How to add a PHP to my html table?* leads me to believe you should read up on the basics

Comment: "I need to implement this php in my html file", you mean the other way around?

Comment: Please ntoe that HTML is parsed and shown by the browser and PHP on the server. So, you *cannot* simply put/call some PHP code in your HTML to perform some action...

Comment: It sounds like you have no PHP experience. Is this a correct assumption?  If so, it sounds like you need a basic PHP tutorial because what you're asking doesn't have a quick, simple answer, thee is some groundwork you need to understand.  You don't just "add PHP to an HTML file".  Maybe this would be a good place to start: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Comment: if i run this code it works like a charm... but now i need to include this in my html code... how can i do that?

Comment: yes i dont have experience with php... so if u guys could tell me how can i do this it would be gr8 :)

Comment: so how could you write that script? Copy and Paste?

Comment: to a index.php it runs good

Comment: I don't see what's so bad about this question. I bet this will be useful to some people despite his not quite getting the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK first of all, you don't *put PHP into HTML*.

PHP is processed at the server, HTML, at the client.

Meaning by time the browser pieces the HTML together, the PHP has already been processed.

From what I can see you'd like [what you have echo'd] to be placed into a HTML element...

```
<?php
$dir = 'xml/';
$output;

$exclude = array('somefile.php', 'somedir');

// Check to see if $dir is a valid directory
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  $contents = scandir($dir);

  $output .= '<select class="dropdown-toggle" id="combo">';

  foreach($contents as $file) {
  // This will exclude all filenames contained within the $exclude array
  // as well as hidden files that begin with '.'
  if (!in_array($file, $exclude) && substr($file, 0, 1) != '.') {
  $output .= '<option>'. $file .'</option>';
  }
  }

  $output .= '</select>';
  }
  else {
  $output .= "The directory <strong>". $dir ."</strong> doesn't exist.";
  }
?>
```

See how I've replaced the echo's with `$output .=`? PHP is now appending those strings to the `$output` variable. That $variable can then be outputted anywhere on your page. I.E:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $output ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You should also know about `include()` but I won't explain as people have already answered accordingly.

Comment: it doesnt show in the html file ... dont i have to call the php like in javascript in the header?

Comment: Yes, you would place your code (The first block in the answer) at the top, either in the `<head>` or before the `<html>` so that the $output variable is written to.

Comment: can u tell me how can i call it if the php is in a diferent file from the index.html like selects.php and use this?

Comment: Yes just place the code block in the `selects.php` file and then in your index.php you would put `<?php include("selects.php") ?>` in your `<head>`

Comment: can you please check what im doing wrong here? http://4zdesigner.com/markers/

I changed to echo again called in the header and in the td and it doesnt show :(

Comment: No I can't check.. PHP is **executed before it hits the browser** so I cant see any PHP by looking on that page.. Why are you changing it to echo? You don't want it echo'd straight away, you want to add it to a variable that will later be echo'd in a table.

Comment: So please dont be mad but im not understanding why it doesnt show... in the php file i use your code that instead of echoing it puts all in a variable, then in the html file i put in the header <?php include("selects.php") ?> and in the td i want i use what?

Comment: Firstly, ensure that `selects.php` is in the same folder as `index.php`. Secondly, just do `<?php echo $output ?>` wherever you want the $output to be echo'd.

Comment: i use this, <?php include("selects.php") ?> but when i inspect appears as  <!--?php include("selects.php") ?--> wich means it apears as a coment dont know why :S

Comment: It's hard for me to tell why, but for some reason your PHP code isn't getting executed. Are you editing the source for this file? (index.php)

Comment: my main file is index.HTML

Comment: That would be why, change the file extension to .php **(index.php)**. Any file that has PHP code to be executed MUST have a .php (or equivalent) file extension.

Comment: Oh and feel free to accept the answer if you got what you needed. (:

Comment: the problem is that i cant change the index.html to php in this assignment

Comment: You've been set an assignment for PHP code and you have to keep the file in HTML format? The word **Impossible** comes to mind. Why can't you change it?

Comment: no i have to make an aplication using googlemaps api, javascript xml and html 5 css etc etc and what i wanted is to dynamicly check all the xml files in a folder and add them to a combobox in the html file so after i click the button and it marks on the map... i have all this done except this part that checks and add to the combobox :)

Comment: OK then AJAX is your alternative. Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div which will contain select generated in php and use javascript to load data, e.g. jquery: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<html>
...
<?php include('codesnippet.php') ?>
...
</html>
```

or the other way (showing the code up in a HTML document)?

```
<pre>
  <code>
    <!-- your snippet goes here, with escaped characters -->
  </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your php right into your page of html wherever you want this select element to appear. Assuming your server will parse an html file for php tags (which is pretty standard) then it will work just like that. If it doesn't, try renaming your .html file to .php.

I would recommend saving your php in a separate file (i.e generate_select.php) then including it wherever you wish, something like this;

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?php include('generate_select.php'); ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can dip in and out of php code whenever you want using php opening and closing tags.